# Convergence of sequences in the one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Consider a 1st countable and Hausdorff space $X$ and its one-point compactification $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$. The topology $\mathcal{T}^\ast$ contains the topology $\mathcal{T}$ of $X$ and all sets of the form $(X \setminus K) \cup \{\infty\} \subset X^\ast$ where $K \subseteq X$ is any compact (and closed) set. Supposedly, one can then show: a sequence $x_n \in X$ converges to $\infty \in X^*$ iff it has no convergent subsequence.

For the backwards implication I came up with the following reasoning: Any subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ does not converge, i.e. for all neighborhoods $U\subset X$ of any point $x \in X$ the subsequence leaves the neighborhood for large enough $k$. Therefore $x_{n_k} \notin U$ and so eventually $x_{n_k} \in (X \setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}$.

However, the converse seems wrong to me. If $x_n \to \infty \in X^\ast$ then for large enough $n$ the sequence is contained in the neighborhoods $U = (X \setminus K) \cup \{ \infty \} \subseteq X^\ast$. So to me it looks like the sequence simply leaves all compact neighborhoods in $X$. How does this imply that there can be no subsequence converging in $X$ somewhere outside of those compact sets? If $X$ were locally compact then any point would have a compact neighborhood, but here $X$ is only 1st countable and Hausdorff, so why does no converging subsequence exist?

Comment: Your reasoning for the backwards implication seems wrong to me - $U$ mightn't be compact. I believe we should require $X$ to be strongly locally compact to get the desired claim, in either direction.

Comment: You're right, but I was thinking that the compact sets are also neighborhoods so the sequence necessarily also leaves those compact sets eventually.

Comment: Why would compact sets also be neighbourhoods? If $x$ is not an isolated point, $\{x\}$ is a compact container of $x$ but isn't a neighbourhood

Comment: Hint for backwards implication: a 1st countable compact topological space is sequentially compact.

Comment: @Jephph: Yes, your hint is helpful. However, one must be more careful, since the one-point-compactification of a first countable space need not be first countable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:
Proofs adapted for one-point compactifications, which are not necessarily Hausdorff.

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff, first countable.
Let $X^* = X \cup \{\infty\}$ be its one-point compactification.
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $X$.

$(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converges to $\infty$, iff $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has no **in $X$** convergent subsequence.

"$\Rightarrow$" is true even without first countability:
Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converge to $\infty$.
Assume $(x_{n_k})_k$ converges to $x \in X$.
Then $K: = \{x_{n_k}: k \in \mathbb N\} \cup \{x\} \subset X$ is compact, hence closed in $X$, since $X$ is Hausdorff.
Hence $(X \setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}$
is a neighborhood of $\infty$, thus $(x_{n_k})_k$ does not converge to $\infty$.
Contradiction.

"$\Leftarrow$":
Assume the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ in $X$ does not converge to $\infty$. Then there is an open neighborhood $U$ of $\infty$ and a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k}$ such that $x_{n_k} \notin U$ for all $k$.
Hence $A := \overline{\{x_{n_k}: k \in \mathbb N\}}$ does not contain $\infty$ (although the closure to be taken in $X^\star$). Hence, $A$ is compact and first countable, therefore sequentially compact (compare the above comment from Jephph). Thus, $(x_{n_k})_{k}$ contains a in $A \subset X$ convergent subsequence, which is also a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$.

Although this was not asked, it might be worthwhile
to note that "$\Leftarrow$" does not hold without first countability:
Let $x \in \beta \mathbb N \setminus \mathbb N$,
$X := \beta \mathbb N \setminus \{x\}$.
Then $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff, not compact.
Its one-point-compactification is homeomorphic to
$\beta \mathbb N$.
The sequence $(n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has no convergent subsequence neither in $X$ nor in $\beta \mathbb N$,
since $\beta \mathbb N$ has no non-trivial convergent sequences at all.
In particular, it does not converge to "$\infty$".

Comment: The same result also holds for $X$ Hausdorff and sequential.  In the proof of $\Leftarrow$ one needs to use that $A$ is sequential as a closed set in a sequential space.  And compact + sequential imply sequentially compact.

Comment: @PatrickR: yes, correct. In fact, for "$\Leftarrow$" you do not need any separation, and in "$\Rightarrow$" Hausdorff can be weakened to KC (= compact subsets are closed).

Comment: Very nice.  And it seems that KC can even be weakened to "weak Hausdorff": as a sequence with its limit, the set $K$ in $\Rightarrow$ can be viewed as the continuous image of a compact Hausdorff space, namely the one point compactification of $\mathbb N$ with the discrete topology.  For an example of space that is weak Hausdorff and not KC: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=weak%20Hausdorff%2B~KC