# Is the one-point compactification of the rationals sequential or Frechet-Urysohn?

Tags: general-topology, compactification

Let $X=\mathbb Q^*=\mathbb Q\cup\{\infty\}$ be the [one-point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of the rationals.  The open sets in $X$ are the open sets in $\mathbb Q$, together with the complements in $X$ of the (closed) compact subsets of $\mathbb Q$.

I have not seen a reference for this, but it seems the following should hold:

> The compactification $X=\mathbb Q^*=\mathbb Q\cup\{\infty\}$ is [Frechet-Urysohn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space).

In other words, if $A\subseteq X$ is not closed in $X$ and $x\in\overline A\setminus A$, there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\omega}$ in $A$ that converges to $x$.  (see start of a proof below)

This is interesting because first countable $\implies$ Frechet-Urysohn $\implies$ sequential $\implies$ compactly generated.  From the properties compiled [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000029/properties) and the references there we already know $X$ is not first countable.  Showing it's Frechet-Urysohn would imply it's compactly generated in the sense of Definition 2 in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactly_generated_space#Definition_2).  On the other hand, the product space $\mathbb Q^*\times\mathbb Q^*$ is *not* compactly generated.  So $\mathbb Q^*$ would provide an example of a compactly generated space whose square is not compactly generated.

---

*(Incomplete) Proof of result*:
Let's write $Y=\mathbb Q$ for convenience.  Take $A\subseteq X$ with $x\in\overline A\setminus A$.

**Case 1**: Suppose $x\in \mathbb Q$.  Then $\mathbb Q$ itself is an open nbhd of $x$ and $\mathbb Q$ is Frechet-Urysohn since it is first countable.  So there is a sequence $(x_n)_n$ in $A\cap\mathbb Q$ that converges to $x$.

**Case 2**: $x=\infty$, so $A\subseteq \mathbb Q$.  We have to show there is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $\infty$.  By definition of the one-point-compactification, saying $\infty\in\overline A$ is equivalent to saying that $A$ is not contained in any compact subset of $\mathbb Q$.  On the other hand, if we can find an infinite discrete subspace $Z\subseteq A$ that is closed in $\mathbb Q$, any enumeration of it would be a sequence converging to $\infty$.  So the proof would boil down to this:

> Suppose $A\subset\mathbb Q$ is not contained in any compact subset of $\mathbb Q$.  Does $A$ necessarily contain an infinite discrete subspace $Z\subseteq A$ that is closed in $\mathbb Q$?

How to show this?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\subseteq\mathbb{Q}$ is not contained in any compact subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., its closure in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not compact), then there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ with no subsequence that converges in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Such a sequence converges to $\infty$ in $\mathbb{Q}^*$ (any compact subset $K\subset\mathbb{Q}$ cannot contain a subsequence of $(a_n)$ so the sequence must eventually be outside of $K$).

Comment: In the first sentence, why is it that there is a sequence in $A$ with no convergent subsequence in $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: The closure of $A$ is not compact so it contains a sequence with no convergent subsequence.  You can then approximate the terms of this sequence with elements of $A$ (making the approximations closer and closer as the sequence goes on).  (More generally, in any metric space, a set has compact closure iff every sequence has a subsequence that converges in the whole space.)

Comment: Or, if you like, the closure of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ must contain either an irrational number or $\pm\infty$, so there is a sequence in $A$ that converges to an irrational number or $\pm \infty$.